# Jenkins org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed

Tags: jenkins, svn, svn-checkout

After upgrading our svn server to version 1.8 we have started to receive build failures. This happens to be occurred in every build project we defined. Note that we are using Jenkins CI v.1.602(installed on Windows 8 x64 OS) and Subversion Plugin v.2.5 for Jenkins. The stack trace from the log is as follows:
(full svn url is omitted for security reasons)

```
ERROR: Failed to check out http://svn.xxx.com.tr/xxxx/trunk/xxx
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/ISPL/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/ISPL/!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:764)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:851)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:115)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:991)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:833)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1750)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
java.io.IOException: Failed to check out http://svn.xxx.com.tr/xxxx/trunk/xxx
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:126)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:162)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:991)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:972)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:948)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:897)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:833)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1750)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. (/ISPL/!svn/vcc/default) 
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/ISPL/!svn/vcc/default'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:764)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:334)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1303)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:851)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:507)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient16.java:915)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:66)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldCheckout.run(SvnOldCheckout.java:18)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1259)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:115)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured it out after a long research on this subject. The root cause of this problem is stemmed from svnkit. Enabling spooling by passing "-Dhudson.spool-svn=true" to JVM options solved it. More details can be found in this link: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1260

Comment: This is still happening in 2015, with svnkit many versions newer.

Comment: Thanks batabek.
I have noticed this issue recently and adding the parameter seems to have corrected the problem, although the checkout seems exceedingly slow.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Subversion server version shouldn't have affected the Subversion client (both the command line client and the SVNKit client). The server should be able to handle clients from version 1.1 to 1.8 without any problems. What's interesting is that your client successfully talked to the server, and your server returned the error.

- What version of Subversion server were you using before?
- Can you do a checkout and update with the Subversion command line client on the Jenkins server? (Yes, you should install the command line client compatible with the working copy you have on your Jenkins server. It helps with debugging issues.)
- Were you using `<Directory>` entities in your server configuration to limit access? If so, you might want to read the [Subversion manual](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#mod_dav_svn-fsmap) about how changes in Subversion 1.7.2 had changed the way it works with Apache. Also remove the SVNAuthPath entities too. This change had [created several issues for users](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/E175002-Server-sent-unexpected-return-value-500-Internal-Server-Error-in-response-to-POST-request-fo-td155129.html) whose previous Subversion configuration stopped working.